# Video.js fullscreen style

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

Working with [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube) for Youtube is working fine in the sample, but in my site fullscreen is not working fine. In fullscreen size, video is moved to the right.

Here is my code:

```
 <script src="scripts/video.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Youtube.min.js"></script>

 <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640" height="264" style="position:absolute; margin-top:300px; margin-left:650px"
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifXalt3MJtM"}] }'>
 </video>
```

And in fullscreen is seen like this (video moved to the right):

[image: error images]

Comment: `style="position:absolute; margin-top:300px; margin-left:650px"` here lies answer to your question.

Comment: @Oen44 without that it works, but how can I add style to the video in simple size?

Comment: Check if video is in fullscreen mode, if not, add that style and vice versa.